# Maven create dependency from external library without groupId/artifactId

Tags: maven

I have a .jar file which I would like to use as an external library. I use IntelliJ with maven and I already imported that .jar file to my libraries in the project structure settings. Now maven gives me an error message when I try to compile since there is no dependency in my `pom.xml`:

```
package de.NeonnBukkit.CoinsAPI.API does not exist.
```

So I would like to create a dependency but I do not know what the groupId and artifactId are. Is there any way to find that out or to add a dependency without groupdId/artifactId?

Comment: The package names look strange... yes check the content of the jar ... often they are packaged with Maven and you will find a `pom.xml` in the directory as @Pino already described... Also you should remove the library from your configuration and readd later only via Maven... IntelliJ will recognize that later... Where have you got the jar from?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where this jar comes from, however for jars created by Maven you can unpack the archive and examine the `META-INF/maven` folder: in one of its subfolders you can find the `pom.xml`.

For jars created manually you can add them to your local repo with a groupId/artifactId of your choice: see https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score -1):

Maven helps you to avoid adding JARs manually, hence you should not keep it directly in classpath and mention it in pom.xml.

If the external JAR has been taken from central Maven repository then its groupId and artifactId can be found at https://mvnrepository.com/. You just need to search JAR name there.

Incase, you have generated JAR from your other personal Maven project, then you need to move it to local repository first and then you can refer same.

You can see steps in this video: https://youtu.be/YwD9N9VYBCw?feature=shared

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).